# Determining whether to create new Objects or update existing ones

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a Person class, and I receive incoming data every 5 seconds about all the people. I either want to make a new Person() or update an existing person. I am having a lot of trouble trying to figure out if that person already exists.

I am using a global array to store all the people objects

```
var people = [];
```

I have fake data coming in

```
var data = {
  id0 : { name : "Billy" },
  id1 : { name : "Joe" }
}
```

If it's a new person it should add it to the people array

```
people[i] = new Person(i);
```

If it's an old person it should just run the update method

```
people[i].update();
```

This is my loop to determine if the person is new or not, but it doesn't work. I know I am kind of comparing apples to oranges. If I could find some way to compare the index name (key) of the people array to the key name of the data object such as

```
if(people[i] === data[i]) // update
else // new
```

My current loop

```
$.each(data, function(i,e){
    console.log(people);
    console.log(i);
    if (people[i] === i) 
        people[i].update(e);
    else 
        people[i] = new Person(e);     
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j6ma2tr2/15/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing objects, which are internally compared based on reference.  So even if the values are identical, if they don't reference the same location in memory, they won't equate.

If you are comparing based on properties, then there should be some unique way to identify a person.  Is it name?  You can compare on the property or series of properties that uniquely identify a person:

```
if (person[i].name === i.name)
//Do something
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to use the index of the data object as the 'unique identifier'. But I guess it's not really that big of a deal.

Comment: If, and only if, this is a correct answer, do you mind marking it as such?

Answer (score 1):

The if branch will always be falsy.  people[i] will never evaluate to the same value as i. You need to find another way to compare the new data and the data which is already in the array.  Perhaps an index field withing the object.